# Is it possible to block reload of some assemblies selectively in Unity Editor?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

Been running into some issues with threading and Unity wherein if a thread was running in the background, and the editor calls a reload, say if you edit a script, eventually or immediately, Unity will crash or freeze.

The issue is because all assemblies get reloaded, and therefore there is a dangling pointer for the threaded assembly/dll.

To further complicate the problem, even if a thread has genuinely completed it's main routine, such as in the case of the running an external executable, and closing that executable, or exiting with an exit code returned, the threads are still not properly cleaned up, and can still cause crashing. Aborting, canceling, and even joining to the main thread don't work either. There's still
something weird going on as soon as Unity reloads ALL of it's assemblies. The log files always show that Unity successfully completes the reload, but immediately after, we have the dangling pointer.

I am aware that you can block reloading with

```
EditorApplication.LockReloadAssemblies();
```

, and even that you can intercept reload with a callback pre reload... But if there is a way to block reloading all together of a specific assemblies, that would solve the crashing problem.

Much simpler would be a folder, say Plugins, where any assembly in there would never recompile.

This problem is not about runtime / play mode, but only inside the Editor, since I am working on production tools & plugins.

Is anyone aware of a solution to this very frustrating problem?

Comment: 5.6 gets around this issue by detecting that the dll has recompiled and automatically exiting Play mode for you and rather than a NPE it throws a softer message saying something to the effect of "play mode terminated due to a recompile of the binaries."

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sadly, this issue goes a bit deeper since A) The problem is entirely in the Editor and nothing to do with Play mode, and B) I do not want the dll to recompile at all, since I want it's state to persist, and even if I wanted to close it, it still causes dangling pointers due to inconsistencies with garbage collection.
This does make me wonder however, if I stuffed the class launching this thread into a game object and set it to DontDestroyOnLoad(this); if that would work.

Comment: That's beyond what I know.

Comment: I was wrong about the DontDestroyOnLoad... that only applies to Play Mode. Assemblies associated with that game object would still be reloaded in the editor at any time a reload was triggered. Madness that you cannot exclude assemblies from reload.... unless you can and I can't find out how. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The solution I went with to contain the memory leaks from IronPython, was to put the scriptengine into it's own appdomain, effectively containing the memory leaks. If you decide to manipulate the editor, this is possible, but if you have it on a thread, you will run into troubles without attempting to dispatch it to the main thread. This includes Debug.Log.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem when using a Thread in the Unity Editor to do some background work.  I was able to solve the hang by aborting and restarting the thread using `UnityEditor.Callbacks.DidReloadScripts`.  Here is the code I tested:

```
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Manager1 
{
    public static int Counter = 0;

    private static Thread Thread;

    static Manager1()
    {
        ThreadStart();
    }

    [UnityEditor.Callbacks.DidReloadScripts]
    static void DidReload()
    {
        Restart();
    }

    static void Task()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Counter++;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    static void Abort()
    {
        Debug.Log("ABORT");
        Thread.Abort();
        Thread = null;
    }

    static void Restart()
    {
        Abort();
        ThreadStart();
    }

    static void ThreadStart()
    {
        Thread = new Thread(Task);
        Thread.Start();
    }
}
```

However, note that I **also** had to add the call to `Thread.Sleep` within the thread. I wasn't able to find any information about this, but I observed that without that call, `ThreadAbortException` is never raised in the thread and the thread of course never ends.

Comment: From my experience and what I've read, thread.Abort() is not the proper way to close a thread and is dangerous. Best to use thread.Interrupt(); and do garbage collection. thread.Join() is also acceptable, though if the main routine in the thread is hanging you will have other issues.

The idea to get the callback on reload of assemblies and cleanup the thread is a good idea though.

Comment: I think you are right.  The way I usually see recommended is to set a flag to signal to the thread to end.  I think the main problem with Thread.Abort is that it doesn't give you control over where in the thread execution will end - in my case, that didn't matter so much.